# Xamarin.IOS UserData from Parse

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, parse-platform

I am trying to make a project where Parse.com is storing my data.

I have two classes:
**User** and 
**UserData**.

When running my code it uses the objectID from **UserData**, however I would like it to get the object from **UserData** by using the username of the current user, which I can fetch with this code:

```
var curUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString ();
```

My **UserData** class contains the a random ObjectID, username which is simlar to the one in the **User** class and also the data rows.

My code currently works with my single user as I have specified the user objectID in the code right now ("***dpLevcJwVP***") , but I don't know how to get any else users data as said before, by using the currents users username.

My code so far which gets the data:

```
    public async void Data()
    {
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("UserData");

        ParseObject userData = await query.GetAsync ("dpLevcJwVP");

        var dataString = userData.Get<string> ("myDataRow");

        Console.WriteLine ("Data fetched: " + dataString);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

Used the following code:

```
    public async void Data()
    {

        var curUser = ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username.ToString ();

        Console.WriteLine ("User: " + curUser);

        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery("UserData")
            .WhereEqualTo("username", curUser);
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();

        ParseObject userData = await query.FirstAsync ();


    }
```